# Using yargs (npm package), how to give an error if command not found?

Tags: javascript, node.js, yargs

I have yargs with 2 commands?

```
yargs
.command('test-all','',handler)
.command('test-file','',handler)
.argv
```

The user inputs:

```
node myapp.js other-command
```

But `yargs` don't throw an error. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.demandCommand()` to do this:

```js
yargs
  .command('test-all','',handler)
  .command('test-file','',handler)
  .demandCommand(1, 'You need at least one command before moving on')
  .argv
```

Comment: It is not answering. The user can give any command. I want to enforce him only to one of the commands I specified.

Comment: @AminadavGlickshtein In that case, instantiate the yargs value and conditionally run `.command()`

Answer (score 2):

You just need to define a command on everything else (* wilcard) that shows the help.

```
yargs
  .command('test-all','',handler)
  .command('test-file','',handler)
  .command('*','', () => { y.showHelp(); })
  .argv
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this now is with:

```
.demandCommand().recommendCommands().strict()
```

This also solves the issue wherein you don't enter any command.

Comment: What each parameter is doing? `demandCommand` `recommendCommands` and `strict` Do we need all? (You can edit the answer)